# Want to generate a docx file and send it as attachment using PHP (PHPMailer)

Tags: php, phpmailer, email-attachments, phpword

I have created a Patient Medical Report form, the work is I want to generate a proper formatted and compatible **docx** file (mostly consist table and paragraph) with value received by the filled form and send it as attachment without saving anywhere.

To create docx file I want to use **PHPWord** plugin and I also tried [HTMLtoDOCX](http://htmltodocx.codeplex.com) for docx generation but I want to send the dynamically generated docx file in attachment. (Don't tell me to use **PHPDocx** because I have its community version and its generating either blank file or file with less text than added)

I am using **PHPMailer** to send Emails. I don't want to attach file use **AddAttachment** Function because it is use for permanent file that is located somewhere.

Currently I am able to send a dynamically generated **doc** file using **PHPMailer** but the file is not compatible with **MS Word 2010** the code for generating doc file and send it as attachment is:

```
    $separator = md5(time());

    $eol = PHP_EOL;

    $headers  = "MIME-Version: 1.0".$eol;
line-4  // $headers .= "Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document".$eol;
line-5  // $headers .= "Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-word.document.macroEnabled".$eol;

    // attachment name
    $filename = $a1 . " Medical Report.doc";

    // Report Document

    $report  = "                    ".$a1 . " Medical Report".$eol.$eol.$eol;
    $report .= "NAME                            |            ".$a1.$eol;
    $report .= "HOSPITAL No.                    |            ".$a2.$eol;
    $report .= "DATE of BIRTH                   |            ".$a3.$eol;
    $report .= "SEX                             |            ".$a4.$eol;
    $report .= "DATE of FOLLOW UP               |            ".$a5.$eol;
    $report .= "DATE of IMPLANT                 |            ".$a6.$eol;
    $report .= "PACEMAKER                       |            ".$a7.$eol;
    $report .= "MODEL                           |            ".$a8.$eol;
    $report .= "PROGRAMMED RATE(bpm)            |            ".$a9.$eol;
    $report .= "MAGNET RATE(bpm)                |            ".$a10.$eol;
    $report .= "EOL/ERT RATE(bpm)               |            ".$a11.$eol;
    $report .= "PROGRAMMED RATE(ms)             |            ".$a12.$eol;
    $report .= "MAGNET RATE(ms)                 |            ".$a13.$eol;
    $report .= "EOL/ERT Rate(ms)                |            ".$a14.$eol;
    $report .= "ATRIAL(amp)                     |            ".$a15.$eol;
    $report .= "RIGHT VENTRICLE(amp)            |            ".$a16.$eol;
    $report .= "LEFT VENTRICLE(amp)             |            ".$a17.$eol;
    $report .= "ATRIAL(pw)                      |            ".$a18.$eol;
    $report .= "RIGHT VENTRICLE(pw)             |            ".$a19.$eol;
    $report .= "LEFT VENTRICLE(pw)              |            ".$a20.$eol;
    $report .= "ATRIAL(mv)                      |            ".$a21.$eol;
    $report .= "RIGHT VENTRICLE(mv)             |            ".$a22.$eol;
    $report .= "LEFT VENTRICLE(mv)              |            ".$a23.$eol;
    $report .= "ATRIAL(ohms)                    |            ".$a24.$eol;
    $report .= "RIGHT VENTRICLE(ohms)           |            ".$a25.$eol;
    $report .= "LEFT VENTRICLE(ohms)            |            ".$a26.$eol;
    $report .= "BATTERY IMPEDANCE               |            ".$a27.$eol;
    $report .= "CALC LONGEVITY                  |            ".$a28.$eol;
    $report .= "BATTERY VOLTAGE                 |            ".$a29.$eol;
    $report .= "ERI INDICATOR                   |            ".$a30.$eol;
    $report .= "CURRENT                         |            ".$a31.$eol;
    $report .= "STABILITY/MYO-POTENTIAL         |            ".$a32.$eol;
    $report .= "VA CONDUCTION                   |            ".$a33.$eol;
    $report .= "WOUND CHECK                     |            ".$a34.$eol;
    $report .= "ECG RHYTHM                      |            ".$a35.$eol;
    $report .= "UNDERLYING RHYTHM               |            ".$a36.$eol;
    $report .= "HISTOGRAMS %AGE PACING          |            ".$a37.$eol;
    $report .= "PATIENT SYMPTOMS                |            ".$a38.$eol;
    $report .= "COMMENTS                        |            ".$a39.$eol;
    $report .= "PROGRAMME CHANGES AND REASONS   |            ".$a40.$eol;  
    $report .= "CARDIAC PHYSIOLOGIST            |            ".$a44.$eol;
    $report .= "NEXT APPOINTMENT                |            ".$a42.$eol;



    // encode data (puts attachment in proper format)
    $attachment = chunk_split(base64_encode($report));

    ///////////HEADERS INFORMATION////////////

    // main header (multipart mandatory) message
    $headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"".$separator."\"".$eol.$eol; 
    $headers .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit".$eol;
    $headers .= "This is a MIME encoded message.".$eol.$eol;

    // message
    $headers .= "--".$separator.$eol;
    $headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"".$eol;
    $headers .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit".$eol.$eol;
    $headers .= $message1.$eol.$eol;

    // attachment
    $headers .= "--".$separator.$eol;
    $headers .= "Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name=\"".$filename."\"".$eol; 
    $headers .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64".$eol;
    $headers .= "Content-Disposition: attachment".$eol.$eol;
    $headers .= $attachment.$eol.$eol;
    $headers .= "--".$separator."--";



    require("class.phpmailer.php");
    $mail = new PHPMailer();

    $mail->IsSMTP();   // set mailer to use SMTP
    $mail->Host = "localhost";  // specify main and backup server
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;     // turn on SMTP authentication
    $mail->Username = "newuser"; // Make sure to replace this with your shell enabled user
    $mail->Password = "wampp";  // Make sure to use the proper password for your user


    $mail->From = "admin@localhost";
    $mail->FromName = "Admin";
    $mail->AddAddress("recepient@domain.com", "First Last");
        $mail->AddCC("recepient@domain.com");
        $mail->AddBCC("recepient@domain.com");

    $mail->AddReplyTo("admin@localhost", "Admin");

    $mail->WordWrap = 50;  // set word wrap to 50 characters
    $mail->IsHTML(true);   // set email format to HTML

    $mail->Subject = $subject;
    $mail->MsgHTML($message1);
    $mail->AddCustomHeader($headers);
    // $mail->AddAttachment($filename, 'Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document;application/vnd.ms.word.document.macroEnabled');

    if(!$mail->Send()){
        echo "Message could not be sent. <p>";
        echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
        exit;
    }
    else {
echo <<<_END
    <script>
        alert("Email Sent");
        document.location='index.html';
    </script>
_END;
    }
?>
```

If I comment out the line-4 and line-5 for docx then I didn't receive the HTML msg and also the file is also changed to a different unsupported word file.

The conclusion of this complete question is that I need the properly formatted **Docx** file according the design I want or the template I have and send it as attachment without any save or download dialog box.

If I use these headers then a dialog box come out with open and save option (I don't want this also)

```
header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=example.docx');
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
```

I hope you all understand what I want. If somebody will give me right direction or solution then 1000000000000000 thanks in advance because I have wasted 2 days on this issue only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not generating a Word file... you're generating plain text and then PRETENDING it's Word by forging the mime headers.

Given that you're using PHPMailer, you should **NOT** be trying to build your own MIME email - PHPMailer already will do that for you perfectly well on its own.

As for not wanting to use a "real" file to store the attachment data, you can use the `AddStringAttachment()` method:

```
  $mailer->AddStringAttachment($your_fake_word_file_as_a_string, 'Example.docx')
```

as detailed here: http://phpmailer.worxware.com/index.php?pg=tutorial#3

Comment: I am very novice in PHP .. I am not getting you properly. I tried your solution but not getting this as attachment. I am only getting **doc** file. and what about PHPWord and HTMLtoDocx.

Answer (score 0):

Use PHPWord to generate Docx files and send it on mail . Its easy to add images, tables, font styles and things like more features,

Read here for more informations about  PHPWord and  its usage.

http://www.kvcodes.com/2014/08/create-docx-files-using-php/